# Chatter Extension CompositionComponentEnumOrId

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chatter-extension

While reading and trying to [Integrate A Custom App into the Chatter Publisher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/components_integrate_customapps_to_publisher.htm)

There is a point where one needs to Set Up a New ChatterExtension Entity via the workbench and we are then prompted with  providing values for ChatterExtension fields with a reference link towards

> [ChatterExtension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_chatterextensions.htm#meta_chatterextensions)

for more information on the field values, however, I am not sure how to get the following values:

- CompositionComponentEnumOrId
- RenderComponentEnumOrId

[image]

Does anyone know where these Id's come from and how to fetch them?

I tried retrieving info via the metadata api, however, there is no such value in the returned file properties:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there is a Trailhead module [Build a Rich Publisher App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/rpa/units/rpa_build#), where it clearly indicates that each is the actuall ID for the Composition and Renderer Components.

> One way to get component values is to go to Setup and search for Lightning Components. Click a listed component to view its details. Copy the component ID from the browser URL.

[image]

However, The documentation fails to mention it verbatim.

Hope this proves useful to anyone